# Inteligencia Artificial usando PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inteligência-artificial

Estou a procurar informações sobre inteligencia artificial usando MySQL e PHP apenas, nao achei muita informação que me orientasse corretamente, eu quero desenvolver um pequeno chat com inteligencia virtual capaz de responder o usuario com base no que ele disse, tipo o Robo ED. Pesquisei e encontrei isso sobre ele

> Segundo a Petrobras, o programa reconhece as palavras-chave, seleciona respostas e escolhe de maneira automática uma das opções para mostrar ao usuário. Quando há muitas palavras em uma mesma frase, o software escolhe uma palavra-chave para responder.

A pergunta é, **COMO** eu posso fazer isso com PHP, qual seria a maneira mais pratica para poder "linkar" o que o usuario disse com as informações do banco de dados.

Comment: Me lembrei do [pt.akinator.com](http://pt.akinator.com/) Não encontrei nenhum tutorial, porém encontrei um *clone* em PHP e MySql Download do [clone do Akinator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/akinator)

Comment: Olá. A sua pergunta ficou realmente ampla porque o assunto é complexo. Sugiro que você leia sobre [PLN (Processamento de Linguagem Natural)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processamento_de_linguagem_natural) e principalmente sobre [AIML (*Artificial Intelligence Markup Language*)](http://www.ginux.ufla.br/files/artigo-LeandroFerreira,JoaquimUchoa.pdf).

Comment: Essa dissertação de mestrado também tem informações úteis (capítulo 2) sobre o AIML e o projeto ALICE: http://www.multicast.com.br/sergio/tuxbot-dissertacao-mestrado-sergio-teixeira.pdf